# upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream

Tags: nginx, server

When I download csv file The browser says "Failed Network error",The nginx server log show "upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream error",my backend server is golang .

Comment: Could you post the logs snippets?

Comment: 2017/10/27 15:33:09 [error] 3203#3203: *6875433 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream, client: , server: , request: "GET /portal/csv/orgDown HTTP/2.0", upstream: "/portal/csv/orgDown", host: "", referrer: ""

Comment: Could you edit the question and provide more information. How big is the file? Could there be a timeout? What is your configuration. A simple generic error message is usually not enough when you ask a question.

Comment: thanks，I found the problem is that my code set the "Content-Length" did not match the actual bytes length.